# How do I develop a formula to find the height of a male using his femur?

Tags: functions, mathematical-modeling

I'm a grade eleven math student and I need a formula to find the height of a 15/16 year old male subject using only the length of his femur. I'm very confused on how to do this, please help, it's for a very important assignment!

Also, I would prefer it in a polynomial function format but if not I can work with that.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

[This website](http://bedtimemath.org/ratios-of-the-human-body/) makes a claim that

> In an adult, the femur is said to be approximately a quarter of a
>   person’s height.

So given the length $x$ of the femur, how would you find the height of the entire person?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is a statistics exercise.  You measure the hight and femur length in a number of males, then plot the data in 2D.  Perhaps you can fit a straight line to the plot.